# WordPress: publication day and title as an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get an array of posts for the current month, which will contain the day of publication and the title, something like this:

```
$events = array(
    array('16' => 'Post Title #1'),
    array('23' => 'Post Title #2'),
    array('23' => 'Post Title #3'),
    array('28' => 'Post Title #4')
);
```

I have little knowledge in this area, so I do so, but it seems to be a bad solution (the array obtained in this way does not work))

```
$currMonth = date('n');
$getEvents = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'    => 'event',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
    'monthnum'    => $currMonth
]);

$events = [];
foreach ($getEvents as $event) {
    $postID = $event->ID;
    $date = get_the_date('d', $postID);
    $title = $event->post_title;
    if ($title) {
        $events[] = '"' . $date . '" => "' . $title . '"';
    }
}

$events = array(implode(',', $events));
```

Not only do I fail with this, but I also feel that this is the wrong approach))). I will be grateful for any help)

Comment: What should happen when you have more than one event happening on a given date? Eg. Event "A" and Event "B" both being held on the 23.

Comment: also get the day of publication and the title

Comment: I changed the array example

Comment: If you want to foreach over the result directly like that, you should really rather use `get_posts` than `new WP_Query`.

Comment: _"the array obtained in this way does not work"_ - you are not creating an array of arrays, you are sticking _string_ values into your array. That should be `$events[] = [$date => $title];`